# Have image change in 1 sec intervals on react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, setinterval

I'm wanting to have an image change to another image every one second. Ideally I want to add quite a few images that have slight variations of the previous that changes one after another. I've created a variable state and an interval function and feel I am on the right path. Obviously what I'm inserting into the image source is incorrect and I'm also not sure where to put the interval timer like 1000. Any help would be appreciated here is my code so far.

```
import "./about.css";
import tb3 from "../../img/tb3.png";
import tb from "../../img/tb.png";

const state = { imageList: [{ tb3, tb }], chosenImgIndex: 0 };

setInterval(() => {
  if (state.chosenImgIndex < state.imageList.length - 1) {
    state.chosenImgIndex++;
  } else {
    state.chosenImgIndex = 0;
  }
});

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className="a">
      <div className="a-left">
        <div className="a-card bg"></div>
        <div className="a-card">
          <img
            src={state.imageList[state.chosenImgIndex]}
            alt=""
            className="a-img"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="a-right">
        <h1 className="a-title">About Me</h1>
        <p className="a-sub">
          lorem ipsum
        </p>
        <p className="a-description">
          <b>How do I stay motivated?</b> Lorem ipsum
        </p>
        <p className="a-description">
          <b>How do I relax?</b> Lorem Ipsum
         
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default About;
```

Answer (score 1):

[setInterval() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) is your friend.

From the documentation:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(myCallback, 500, 'Parameter 1', 'Parameter 2');

function myCallback(a, b)
{
 // Your code here
 // Parameters are purely optional.
 console.log(a);
 console.log(b);
}
```

So in your case, you would do something like:

```
setInterval(() => {
  if (state.chosenImgIndex < state.imageList.length - 1) {
    state.chosenImgIndex++;
  } else {
    state.chosenImgIndex = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: and then what would I put in my img src ={} ?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the `img src` part. If you set up the interval correctly, it should work, unless you are defining `setInterval` inside the component, so it is re-defined at every render.

Comment: this is what is console.logging every second 
{tb3: '/static/media/tb3.60119f638d5a75a97a2f.png', tb: '/static/media/tb.06b23125daa7c72a56d3.png'} should it not be one or the other?

Comment: Try to `console.log(state.imageList[state.chosenImgIndex])` every second. If it changes every second, then your `<img>` is the problem (for example, the component is not re-rendering). If it doesn't change every second, you are calling `setInterval` in some wrong way.